# Como aplicar css a uma página aberta com window.open?

Tags: javascript, css

Tenho uma página da qual eu preciso imprimir apenas uma parte, utilizei o window.open seguido de um window.print para isso, só que a impressão não sai no formato esperado, é um formulário e deve ser impresso tal qual está num arquivo css que eu tenho, como faço para quando criar essa nova janela ela conter o css? tentei com href, target_blank e referenciando no document.write mas não teve jeito.

segue o código usado para abrir a página de impressão:

```
$('#btnPrint').click(function() {
                var prtContent = document.getElementById("dados");
                var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'left=0,top=0,width=800,height=900,toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,status=0');
                WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML,);
                WinPrint.document.close();
                WinPrint.focus();
                WinPrint.print();
                document.getElementById('dados').remove()
                WinPrint.close();
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vc pode rconstruir outro html nessa janela de impressão e chamar o CSS dessa forma por exemplo

```
WinPrint.document.write('<html><head><title>Print it!</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"></head><body>');
WinPrint.document.write($("#content").html());
WinPrint.document.write('</body></html>');
```

Aqui vc pode consultar outras forma nessa resposta do STOF em inglês: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758288/open-a-new-javascript-window-open-along-with-its-css-styling

Comment: Já tentei fazer isso e a janela de impressão abre em branco, acredito que estou errando em alguma coisa "básica" mas não consigo perceber exatamente no que. Vou dar uma olhada nas outras opções da pergunta em inglês e ver se alguma delas resolve.